# Deploying Django on VPS using Apache2 mysql using Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, django, apache, ubuntu, vps

I am trying to deploy my project on VPS(Ubuntu). I tried following all the steps from the Django documentation as well as other websites without any success.

My issue is that when i run the server, it will be alive only till the terminal is open.

So i am predicting that there is some issue with the procedure am using.

I am using Django with Apache2, mod_wsgi, cartridge, mysql, python.

I am now struck with a VPS and nothing in mind.

I wish if somebody could suggest me tutorial or any documentation which will help me continue.

I have successfully run the server on Ubuntu VPS. But it is on Development server.

thanks in advance

Sameer

Comment: How have you deployed it? Seems like you are using manage.py runserver rather than actually configuring Apache. Post your configuration.

Comment: Hello Daniel, i have configured apache2, but all i get is the default index.html on the address. Yes you are right, i am using manage.py runserver. I know Django should work without the runserver command. But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Did you look at the very good [documentation on deploying with Apache/mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)?

Comment: Yes. I have followed the same documentation. Only thing is i didn't create virtual environment. Is that necessary?

Comment: You can't possibly have followed that documentation if you're still using runserver. No, virtualenv is not necessary, but configuring Apache is.

Comment: I don't know what i am missing. Let me try and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will use this [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/using-mod_wsgi-to-serve-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04) please do not miss any step after complete all steps you will able to run your application.

there are more guideline's, follow the step by step.

http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/09/14/django-in-virtualenv-on-webfactions-apache-with-mod-wsgi/
https://library.linode.com/frameworks/django-apache-mod-wsgi/ubuntu-10.10-maverick

Comment: Thank you. Let me try these links.

Comment: I have successfully started Apache with Django project. Thank you guys for your help.