# can't reload apache with wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

So I'm following the tutorial on Django on how to deploy : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

I copypasted this in httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

and now all my websites are redirected to my django app
so I tried puting a VirtualHost around that script, and if I do that I cannot reload apache2. Any idea why or how I should do it?

Comment: You use these documentation for better understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257894/deploying-django-on-vps-using-apache2-mysql-using-ubuntu/21261411#21261411

Comment: it seems like it's because of WSGIPythonPath that I cannot reload Apache. I can reload without this line (although I get an Error 500 when I visit my website)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long I've been up working on that problem. But I found something:

WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

If I write this line I can't reload apache.

So I removed it, and I wrote:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myproject/')
```

in wsgi.py

and it works :)

Comment: What is the actual error in the Apache error logs. There is no reason WSGIPythonPath shouldn't work unless you simply put it in the wrong place in the Apache configuration file.